# map is not a function and picker problem in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, picker

I have problem with map my array about curriences.
so as u see there is a curriences array with strings. Im using Picker to choose some between them and I have function what is included to `onValueChange` prop in Picker, and then comes my problem with selecting an item from picker.

Firstly I can choose a whatever item from picker, but when I want to choose again I have just this choosed item before in the list:

[image: there is 1st step]

then i choosed for example EUR. When I want to choose a item again I have just this:

[image: there is 2nd step]

Also when I change first picker item - it changes also in the second picker... don't know why.

also adding whole code here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, Picker} from 'react-native';
class CurrencyCashScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR'],
    base: 'PLN',
    amount: '',
    convertTo: 'EUR',
    result: '',
    date: '',
  };

  handleSelect = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        currencies: [itemValue],
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };

  handleInput = text => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        amount: text,
        result: null,
        date: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };

  calculate = () => {
    const amount = this.state.amount;
    if (amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.state.base}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const date = data.date;
          const result = (data.rates[this.state.convertTo] * amount).toFixed(4);
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            result,
            date,
          });
        });
    }
  };

  handleSwap = e => {
    const base = this.state.base;
    const convertTo = this.state.convertTo;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        convertTo: base,
        base: convertTo,
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
    );
  };
  render() {
    const {currencies, base, amount, convertTo, result} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {amount} {base} is equevalent to
        </Text>
        <Text>
          {amount === '' ? '0' : result === null ? 'Calculating...' : result}{' '}
          {convertTo}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                keyboardType="numeric"
                value={amount}
                onChangeText={this.handleInput}
              />
              <Picker
                selectedValue={base}
                value={base}
                onValueChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {currencies.map((currency, index) => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}>
                    {currency}
                  </Picker.Item>
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                editable={false}
                value={
                  amount === ''
                    ? '0'
                    : result === null
                    ? 'Calculating...'
                    : result
                }
              />
              <Picker
                selectedValue={convertTo}
                value={convertTo}
                onValueChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {currencies.map(currency => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}>
                    {currency}
                  </Picker.Item>
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text onClick={this.handleSwap}>CLICK ME</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrencyCashScreen;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below example

you need  two separate functions

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, Picker} from 'react-native';

class CurrencyCashScreen extends Component {
 state = {
    currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR'],
    base: 'PLN',
    convertTo: 'EUR',
    amount: '',
    result: '',
    date: '',
  };

 handleSelectPicker1 = itemValue => {
    this.setState(
      {
      base:itemValue
      },
    );
  };

  handleSelectPicker2 = itemValue => {
    this.setState(
      {
        convertTo:itemValue
      },
    );
  };

render() {
    const {currencies, base, amount, convertTo, result,pickerValue1,pickerValue2} =     this.state;
    console.log('this.state',pickerValue1,pickerValue2)
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={base}
                //value={base}
                onValueChange={this.handleSelectPicker1}>
                {currencies.map((currency, index) => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}/>
                ))}
              </Picker>

              <Picker
                selectedValue={convertTo}
                //value={convertTo}
                onValueChange={
                this.handleSelectPicker2
                }>
                {currencies.map(currency => (
                  <Picker.Item label={currency} value={currency}/>
                ))}
              </Picker>
          </View>
    );
  }

}

export default CurrencyCashScreen;
```

hope this will help you. Change this according to your requirement. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Technically [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) requires an array to be executed on the variable.

I guess `itemValue` is not an array what you pass to `handleSelect`. That's why you have that error. I think if you modify the code to handle `currencies` as an array then it should work.

```
handleSelect = itemValue => {
   this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        currencies: [itemValue],
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate,
   );
};
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well, It almost works. Now I can select an item from my picker. But when I choose some, I cant choose other value again. Also I think I will pase my all code

Answer (score 0):

More than likely `currencies` is not an array. Here is what I recommended:

- Check to make sure that you've properly destructured your state earlier in the render function like `const { currencies } = state;` Any typos here may cause the error.
- Make sure `currencies` is set with a sane default. If `currencies` is undefined when your component first mounts, you will get this error.
- Use `console.log`, or a debugger to view the value of `currencies`. If it is not an array (including `undefined`) when you call the `currencies.map` method, then you will get this error.

Comment: I think I should edit post and pase whole code here becouse I think there is something else what giving the problem.